# Factors that influence the selection of the right tool - NiFi vs Streamsets

Tags: bigdata, apache-nifi

I am trying to decide between NiFi and Streamsets as my Data Ingest tool and would like to know what should be my deciding factors for chosing the most appropriate tool.  For instance the type of transformations that are required, the types of Source systems and the type of Target systems etc I am sure will tip the scale in favor of one of the tool.  I am looking for guidance on the factors to be considered while making the selection of one vs the other. Thanks, Raj

Answer (score 2):

You have basically enumerated all the important factors of data ingestion tool choice. Both of those tools have similar features.

When we are talking NiFi vs. Streamsets, the good comparison was done here: [Difference between Apache NiFi and StreamSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899612/difference-between-apache-nifi-and-streamsets), although nowadays both technologies have been improved.

Some more factors can be:

- the maturity of the tool - the year it was released (NiFi was first)
- size of open source community - based on https://www.openhub.net/p/streamsets-data-collector and https://www.openhub.net/p/nifi , Nifi has had more contributors and commits
- Apache project - Nifi is Apache project, whereas Streamsets is only Apache licensed

I think both of them can be used for various use cases and the differences are not so big. There can be differences based on the specific use case (which you did not specify), but nowadays there does not exist so much complex decision algorithm as you've requested.